# Conscrypt SSL - Jetty Configuration

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

As far as enabling Conscrypt SSL I'm a little confused on where the Jetty config files are manipulated to enable the necessary modules.

I'm using dropwizard(1.3.0-rc6).

The [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-ssl-distribution.html#jetty-conscrypt-distribution) docs go into some detail about it. It is my understanding that most of Jetty's config files are packed into a `config.yml` file that ships with dropwizard. So I don't understand how `$JETTY_BASE` and `$JETTY_HOME` are accessible through dropwizards implementation. Jetty is pulled in by dependency apart of Dropwizards core. If I want to edit Jetty connectors for examples, do I need to manually recreate [httpconnector](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty) for example.

How to edit Jetty's sslContextFactory file to set Conscrypt as the security provider?

Answer (score 0):

After some reading.. I had jetty installed locally with brew. 
 So `/usr/local/Cellar/` is where brew installs packages. 
cd into `/jetty/libexec` this is where the `start.jar / start.ini` are. 
Then you run the jar with arguments to add the ssl and conscrypt modules. `java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=ssl,conscrypt` 
I still don't believe this has anything to do with dropwizards configuration of jetty, so because of this how can the jetty configuration shipped with dropwizard be changed?
 Or do I pull in my machines local implementation of Jetty, and exclude Dropwizards version of it?